# STS 3.7.0 crashes on start-up, Windows 7, 64 bit

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, windows-7-x64, spring-tool-suite

I recently downloaded the zip file of spring tool suite(3.7.0) from it's official web page(https://spring.io/tools/sts/all). After unzipping it and double clicking the sts.exe file, it asks for the namespace. After that when sts loads, the dashboard appears but after few seconds the application crashes. I'm getting the following error popup..

[image: error popup]

And also a log file is generated whose first few lines are..

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x000007fee5f4ca90, pid=5020, tid=3860
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr120.dll+0x8ca90]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I can't seem to understand where I am going wrong. I installed both 32, 64 bit JDK on my machine just in case but still nothing. Is it because windows did not install properly on my laptop?? Please help..

**EDIT 1:**

In response to @Pendlimarri's comment below, the different forms of Java installed in my control panel are[image: control panel]..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too got the same problem. I fixed by `uninstalling` the 1.8.0_60 update from `Control Panel`.
This might be a `bug` in `1.8.0_60`.

Comment: @Pendlimarri's...Please look at the screen-shot I attached to the question and advise me which 1.8.0_60 update to remove??

Comment: @Lucy.. I think you directly installed **1.8.0_60**. You are using Windows-7-x64, So.. Uninstall 4'th one first. i.e. **Java 8 Update 60 (64bit**) and try. If you face the same issue, please remove the 1'st (**Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 60**) and 2'nd (**Java 8 Update 60**)and reboot your machine and then try. It will surely work.

Comment: @Pendlimarri's....I uninstalled jdk 1.8 completely from my machine. Then installed jdk 1.7(64 bit)..Now STS is working perfectly...Thanks a lot for your help...I was thinking this was OS issue but you proved otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, it's probably because STS is 32-bit and your JDK is 64-bit - change one or the other and it should work